# Biblioteca PHPMAILER enviando emails duplicados

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tenho um código PHP que envia dados para o PHPMailer (dados resultantes de uma consulta no banco de dados).

O problema é que quando o PHPMailer dispara o email, ele chega duplicado na caixa de entrada de quem deveria receber o email.

```
public function editarChamados()
{   
  try 
  {
      $c = new Conexao();
      $db = $c->conectar();                                 

      if($this->descricao <> "")
      {                                 
          $descricao = "Olá";
            
        $query = "START TRANSACTION;
        SET @responsavel := (SELECT usuario FROM usuarios_ti WHERE id = :responsavel_ti);
        UPDATE chamados SET id_usuario_ti = :responsavel_ti, titulo = :titulo WHERE id = :id;
        INSERT INTO dialogo_chamados(id_chamado,dialogo,remetente)VALUE(:id,'$descricao',@responsavel);                                     
      COMMIT;
      ";

      $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bindValue(":responsavel_ti",$this->responsavel_ti);    
      $stmt->bindValue(":titulo",$this->titulo);                        
      $stmt->bindValue(":id",$this->id);    

      if($stmt->execute())
      {
      //Chamando método que envia o email
      $this->enviarEmail();
      echo "sucesso";
      die();                            
      }
      else
      {
      print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
      }


      }                                                 

  } 
  catch(PDOException $e) 
  {
    echo "Erro: ".$e->getCode()." Mensagem: ".$e->getMessage();             
  }
}

//Método de envio de email
public function enviarEmail()
{

    $c = new Conexao();
    $db = $c->conectar();

    $query = "SELECT a.dialogo, a.remetente, a.data_dialogo, b.solicitante FROM dialogo_chamados AS a 
    INNER JOIN chamados AS b ON b.id = a.id_chamado WHERE b.id = :id ORDER BY a.data_dialogo";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id",$this->id);                  
    $stmt->execute();           

    $dialogos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    try
    {

        $nome_remetente = $this->nome_responsavel_ti;
        $email_remetente = $this->email_responsavel_ti;
        $email_destinatario = $this->email_solicitante;
        $titulo_chamado = $this->titulo;
        $data_abertura_chamado = $this->data_abertura_chamado;

        $mailer->setLanguage('br');
        $mailer->CharSet = "utf8";
        $mailer->IsSMTP();
        //$mailer->SMTPDebug = 4;
        $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mailer->Host = "smtp.skymail.net.br";
        $mailer->Port = 587;
        $mailer->Username = 'suporte@jca.com.br';
        $mailer->Password = "54h54fg6j4g6j";
        $mailer->Priority = 1;
        $mailer->addReplyTo($email_remetente, $nome_remetente);
        $mailer->setFrom('suporte@jca.com.br', "JCA - Suporte Tecnico");
        $mailer->AddAddress($email_destinatario);
        $mailer->IsHTML(true);
        $mailer->Subject = 'Mensagem do Suporte Tecnico';
      
        $mensagem = "CONTEÚDO DO EMAIL";
     
        $mailer->Body = $mensagem;

        if($mailer->Send())
        { 
          $mailer->ClearAllRecipients();
          $mailer->ClearAttachments();
        } 
        else 
        { 
          echo "Mailer Error: " . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
          die();
        }   

    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
       echo "Erro: ".$e->getCode()." Mensagem: ".$e->getMessage();
    }                           
}
```

[image: - Caixa de entrada do Email:]

Comment: @hkotsudo, como eu faço para postar códigos PHP aqui no Stackoverflow ? Nunca consigo postar corretamente, pois parece que aqui não tem um local adequado para postar códigos PHP. Eu poderia, por exemplo, postar o código em um Pastebin e colocar o link na descrição de pergunta ?

Comment: O ideal é que o código sempre esteja na pergunta e links sirvam apenas como complemento (se o código original é muito grande, tente reduzi-lo para um [mcve]). De qualquer forma, o código desta pergunta está ok, não sei o que tem de errado pra vc achar que não está postado corretamente (ele só não executa diretamente na página, mas essa funcionalidade é restrita a JavaScript, HTML e CSS)

Comment: Sabe dizer se existe algum redirecionamento no e-mail do destinatário?

Comment: Depois lembra de alterar a senha desse email 'suporte@jca.com.br'

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu digo em relação a organização, indentação , etc... Sempre quando ppsto os códigos aqui, eles saem bem desorganizados. Não saem conforme estão no meu editor de texto.

Comment: @ThiagoCosta , não é essa.

Comment: @ThiagoCosta , não existe.

Comment: @Gambi Não sei, eu sempre posto códigos aqui e nunca tive problemas com formatação. O máximo que posso te sugerir é dar uma lida na centra de ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @hkotsubo , onde você posta código php aqui ?

Comment: Funcionou, adicionei o código $mailer->ClearAddresses(); dentro do if($mailer->send()). Agora preciso saber o porquê disso ter acontecido. Mas o problema já foi resolvido.

Comment: Eu sempre coloco o código nas próprias perguntas/respostas. Às vezes, quando é interessante mostrar o código rodando, eu coloco em algum IDE online (como o ideone.com, repl.it, etc), mas sempre como um complemento - se o código é essencial para a responder a pergunta, então deve estar sempre aqui no próprio site (como eu já disse, links externos devem ser apenas complementos)

Comment: @hkotsubo , obrigado!

Comment: Agora está tudo liberado. O carinha só mudou o PHPMAILER por PHPMailer na edição da pergunta. Se for assim, o Stackoverflow virará um "mar de edições".

Comment: ... Pior que as pessoas estão negativando a pergunta, mas não sabem o quão útil é a informação contida na resposta e também o quão chato é passar pelo problema relatado na pergunta. Mas tá valendo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Resolvi o problema utilizando o método, do PHPMAILER, `ClearAddresses()`.
- Andei lendo e vi que esse método serve para excluir os endereços de destino que foram passados anteriormente no método `AddAddress()`.

A parte do código que alterei, ficou assim:

```
if($mailer->Send())
{ 
    $mailer->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mailer->ClearAttachments();
    $mailer->ClearAddresses(); 
}
```

Referência: [Programacion.net](https://programacion.net/articulo/uso_de_la_clase_phpmailer_213)